# Location of passwords file in Firefox 15 (Windows 8)?

Tags: firefox, password-management, firefox-sync

On Windows 8, where does Firefox save a users password? I think on older Firefox versions it was in "signons.txt" but I couldn't find this file on my entire hard drive - so perhaps this has changed in recent firefox builds?

I know I can see the passwords via the Firefox GUI, but I want to keep a cleartext copy of the password as a backup somewhere (in an encrypted Truecrypt volume with a strong key). I want to do the same for my Chrome password but that's a separate question I guess ...

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file is [`signons.sqlite`](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Password_Manager#Backing_up_and_restoring_passwords), starting with Firefox 3.5. You will also need `key3.db`, which contains the master key that all stored passwords are encrypted with. See Mozilla's advice on [backing up passwords](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Password_Manager#Backing_up_and_restoring_passwords).